# Should 'null' be considered numeric? …alphanumeric?

Tags: java, null, numeric, alphanumeric

I guess this question is less technical and more philosophical.

I'm writing some Java classes that act as containers of data that could be imported from a variety of formats,  including JSON and SQL result sets, both of which could contain null values. These classes share two methods, `isNumeric()` and `isAlphanumeric()`.

**How should these methods treat null values?**
Are null values inherently numeric? Are they alphanumeric? I can come up with at least plausible justifications either way. I guess I'm just interested in hearing what the community's opinion might be.

Comment: null is, by definition, **nothing**.

Comment: They should both return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This describes how null is defined in Oracle-
http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php?8666-What-is-the-data-type-of-NULL

Comment: This is interesting in that the _data type_ becomes "character" but the character _representation_ of null is a non-printable special entity, and thus neither numeric nor alphanumeric. This would seem to point to `false` as the canonical return type for these methods.

Answer (score 1):

Null values are neither numeric nor alphanumeric - rather, they are an absence of value (and type).

Comment: That's conceptually true, but the methods do return a `boolean`, so "neither" isn't an option. ^_^

Comment: You mean `isNumeric` and `isAlphaNumeric`? - they should both return `false` for `null`.